# How to use GITHUB_TOKEN in pip's requirements.txt without setting it as env variable in Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker

I have a private repos that can be installable via python's pip:

## requirements.txt

```
git+https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/MY_ACCOUNT/MY_REPO.git
```

And a Dockerfile:

## Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.11

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install gcc curl && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ARG GITHUB_TOKEN
COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```

It worked perfectly when i build up an image:

`$ docker build . --build-arg GITHUB_TOKEN=THIS_IS_MY_GITHUB_TOKEN -t wow/my_app:latest`

But when I inspected image, it shows `GITHUB_TOKEN` in `Cmd` section:

`$ docker image inspect wow/my_app:latest`

```
...
"ContainerConfig": {
    ...
    "Cmd": [
        "|1",
        "GITHUB_TOKEN=THIS_IS_MY_GITHUB_TOKEN",     # Here!
        "/bin/sh",
        "-c",
        "pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt"
    ],
    ...
},
...
```

I think this could lead to a security problem. How can I solve this so that anything credential info not appear in `docker inspect`?

Comment: @rv.kvetch `ENV` values are also baked into the resulting image and are available for inspection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build your image using [BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/), you can take advantage of Docker [build secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#secret).

You would structure your Dockerfile something like this:

```
FROM python:3.8.11

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install gcc curl && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=GITHUB_TOKEN \
  GITHUB_TOKEN=$(cat /run/secrets/GITHUB_TOKEN) \
  pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
```

And then if you have a `GITHUB_TOKEN` environment variable in your local environment, you could run:

```
docker buildx build --secret id=GITHUB_TOKEN -t myimage .
```

Or if you have the value in a file, you could run:

```
docker buildx build \
  --secret id=GITHUB_TOKEN,src=github_token.txt \
  -t myimage .
```

In either case, the setting will not be baked into the resulting image. See the linked documentation for more information.